# Как сделать что бы пользователь только с определенной ролью мог пользоваться командой(например clear)

Tags: python, discord.py

Вот код самой команды clear

@client.command()

async def clear(ctx, amount = 10):
await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)

Мне нужно что бы когда пользователь с конкретной ролью вводил команду то она работала. Если у пользователя нету конкретной роли то команда не работала. Мой вопрос может показаться глупым но я только изучаю пайтон и данную библиотеку так что пожайлуста подскажите.(библиотека discord.py)

Answer (score 0):

[С документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role()# в скобках вы можете указати айди роли или её назву
async def clear(ctx, amount = 10): 
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
```